# Perl 5 signatures: Passing multiple arrays

Tags: perl, prototype, signature

I was hoping that with the signatures feature in Perl 5 (e.g. in version 5.34.0), something like this would be possible:

```
use feature qw{ say signatures };

&test(1, (2,3,4), 5, (6,7,8));

sub test :prototype($@$@) ($a, @b, $c, @d) {
    say "c=$c";
};
```

Or perhaps this:

```
sub test :prototype($\@$@) ($a, \@b, $c, @d) {
}
```

(as suggested here: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11109414).

However, I have not been able to make that work. My question is: With the signatures feature, is it possible to pass more than one array to a subroutine?

Alternatively: Even with signatures, is the only way to pass arrays by reference? That is to say: Are there any alternatives to passing by reference, e.g.:

```
sub test($a, $b, $c, @d) {
  my @b = @{$b};
}
```

Many thanks!

(P.S.: If there's a solution for arrays, then there'd be one for hashes as well, so I haven't spelled that out above.)

Comment: You can't use parentheses like that. A statement `1, (2, 3, 4), 5` is not an array inside two scalars, it is a list of 5 scalars. All parentheses do is change the precedence of the nearby operators (in this case, changes nothing). For example: `$a = 4 * (3 + 1)` (16, not 13).

Comment: You can use prototypes to force a sub to act like a built-in function (like `push @foo, $bar`) and take an array argument. Or so I hear. Prototypes are not Perl's best feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the signatures feature, is it possible to pass more than one array to a subroutine?

Yes you can do this:

```
use v5.22.0;   # experimental signatures requires perl >= 5.22
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);

sub test :prototype($\@$\@) ($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    say "c=$c";
}

my @q  = (2,3,4);
my @r  = (6,7,8);
test(1, @q, 5, @r);
```

**Output**:

```
c=5
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. For me, this only works as `test(1, \@q, 5, \@r);`, i.e., passing the arrays as reference, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @bjohas Hmm.. that is strange. It works fine here. Did you use exactly the same script as shown above? What error message or output did you get?

Comment: This works for me for Perl 5.34. If you move up to 5.26, you can use the declared_refs feature "my \@b = $b; my \@d = $d;" to make accessing the arrays more ergonomic.

Comment: @bjohas Why do you want to avoid passing arrays as references? It's literally just typing a few characters extra. Is it just about how it looks?

Comment: @Håkon. Thank you for the discussion - I really appreciate it! So yes, my comment was wrong...  Let me add some text.

Comment: now done. So yes, it's just an optical thing: I would like to be able to say @b in the parameter list. But you're right, in terms of typing, there isn't much of a difference.

Comment: @bjohas If you have a lot of arguments, the right solution might be to make an object and pass that along. I seldom use prototypes and signatures, they are often just more trouble than they are worth and can be skipped entirely.

Comment: Re "*passing the arrays as reference, which I'd like to avoid*", Impossible. The only thing that can be passed to subs are scalars (and it's the only thing they can return).

Answer (score 1):

As per suggestion in comment thread, summarising some of the ideas in a separate answer:

### Proposed solution by Håkon Hægland

```
sub test :prototype($\@$\@) ($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    say "c=$c";
    say @$b;
}

my @q  = (2,3,4);
my @r  = (6,7,8);
test(1, @q, 5, @r);
```

### The usual pass-by-reference

Note that this is different from traditional pass by reference:

```
my @q  = (2,3,4);
my @r  = (6,7,8);

sub test1 :prototype($$$$) ($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    say "c=$c";
    say @$b;
}

test1(1, \@q, 5, \@r);
```

Håkon's solution has the benefit of validation (and means that args are passed as `@b` rather than `\@b`).

### Improvement with declared_refs

Diab Jerius suggested declared_refs, which is offers alternative syntax:

```
use v5.22.0;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures declared_refs);

sub test :prototype($\@$\@) ($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    say "c=$c";
    say @$b;
    my \@bb = $b;
    say @bb;
}
```

### What I (original poster) had hoped.

I was hoping that (mainly for optics) this would be possible

```
sub test :prototype($@$@) ($a, @b, $c, @d) {
    say @b;
};
```

Comment: Re "*The usual pass-by-reference*", Perl *always* passes by reference. What you call "passing by reference" is actually just "passing references"